# Error: Failed to load plugin prettier: Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-prettier'

Tags: reactjs, web, travis-ci, eslint, yarnpkg

It works fine in local. But when I push to github, it cannot pass the Travis. The package shows which I do not have, actually in my package.json. I use eslint, because I followed [eslint-prettier-airbnb](https://blog.echobind.com/integrating-prettier-eslint-airbnb-style-guide-in-vscode-47f07b5d7d6a)

[It says cannot load the module when it passes the travis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmLdP.png)

It uses node v8.16,

```
package.json
    "eslint": "^5.3.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^4.3.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^2.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.17.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.13.0",
```

```
.eslintrc

{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true,
    "jest": true
  },
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "airbnb", "prettier"],
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "experimentalObjectRestSpread": true,
      "jsx": true
    },
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "plugins": ["react", "prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
  }
}
```